# SSH key with BitBucket doesn't seem to work

Tags: bitbucket, ssh-keys

I generated an SSH key on my server by doing these commands:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "address@email.com"
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I saved it to my BitBucket account.

Then, I dit `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` and I received the following answer :

> You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.

But when I'm doing a simple `git pull origin master` on one of my repositories, it asks me again my password.

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Your git client has no way of knowing that you've created a new SSH key, or that you've added the public key to Bitbucket, unless you change the remote URLs for the repositories that are hosted there.

To see what the repository remote's URL is, cd to the local repo and run `git remote get-url origin`.

To change the origin remote's URL to an SSH one, run `git remote set-url username@bitbucket.org:owner/repo.git` (replacing `username`, `owner`, and `repo.git` with appropriate values).